# Sharepoint contentDB migration issue

Tags: 2013, migration

I am trying to restore a Sharepoint2010 content database(SQL Server 2008 R2) to a Sharepoint 2013 contentDB(SQL Server 2008 R2), on two different servers.
On running the `Mount-ContentDatabase` command in Sharepoint Management Shell I am getting the following error.

> sequence
>   [Microsoft.sharepoint.upgrade.spcontentdatabasesequence]cannot upgrade
>   an object [spcontentdatabasename name]whose build
>   version[12.0.0.6565]is too old. upgrade requires [14.0.4762.1000] or
>   higher

Though its clear that there is some version issue but I have done a couple of migrations earlier using same two DB Servers, didn't face any problem.
Any idea why this error came all of sudden and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually version 12.0.* is not SP2010, but SP2007 database, in order to migrate to SP2013 you first need to upgrade that DB in place on your SP2010 server via `stsadm -o addcontentdb`, then you detach it and attach to SP2013, which will perform one more upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is actually a SharePoint 2007 database.  Mount the database to a 2010 web application to upgrade it and then mount it to a 2013 web application.